# Count lines with different characters

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression

I am trying to write a command  that examines a file which name has been given as a
parameter, and prints out the number of different lines containing exactly 7 characters.
I was doing it using `grep` and `find`, but I am going wrong.
What should I use, or what pattern?

Comment: Can you give an example file (with contents) and our exact desired output?

Comment: give some example contents of file.   if you want to count the lines which is having exactly 7 characters, then you can use this.   grep -c "^.......$" filename

Answer (score 2):

This could be your command. It's a script that takes a filename on the command line and outputs all lines in it that has exactly seven characters:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -c '^.......$' "$1"
```

You have to make the above script executable (with something like `chmod +x script.sh`), and then run it with `./script.sh file` where `file` is the name of the file that you'd like to examine.

The command

```
grep -c '^.......$'
```

will output the number of lines in the given file that contains exactly seven characters (including spaces).

This may be shortened to

```
grep -cEx '.{7}'
```

The `-E` in necessary because the expression is now an *extended regular expression*. The `-x` flag will force the expression to match a full line.

If you don't want to count spaces and you're only interested in "word characters" (alphanumerics), you may use

```
grep -cExw '.{7}'
```

The `-w` flag to `grep` will force the match to be a "word" (a string of alphanumeric characters delimited by non-alphanumeric characters).

If you want to count how many *unique* lines there are that fulfill this criteria (this is how I interpret "different lines"), then pipe the result of `grep` without the `-c` flag through `uniq` and `wc -l`. This will count the number of unique lines with exactly seven word characters.

```
grep -Exw '.{7}' | uniq | wc -l
```

In the script, this becomes

```
grep -Exw '.{7}' "$1" | uniq | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -l -0777pe '$_ =()= /^.{7}$/gm' "$1"

awk 'length == 7' "$1" | wc -l

sed -Ee '/.{8}/d; /.{7}/!d' "$1" | grep -c .
```